# JPA Converter with contains query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm having some trouble with a particular query in my Spring Boot application. I'm using Spring's built-in text encryption in order to encrypt text in my database

I have an entity called BookRecord

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class BookRecord extends Auditable {

@EmbeddedId
private BookIdentifier identifier;

@Column(name = "title")
@Convert(converter = TitleEncryptionConverter.class)
private String title;
```

And a title encryption converter which looks like this

```
public class TitleEncryptionConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {
    private TextEncryptor textEncryptor;

    public TitleEncryptionConverter (TextEncryptor textEncryptor) {
        this.textEncryptor = textEncryptor;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
        return textEncryptor.encrypt(attribute);
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return textEncryptor.decrypt(dbData);
       }
    }
```

I'm trying to search the database using a "contains" on the title, however because the title is encrypted I'm having trouble getting the proper results. Here is my query:

```
Page<BookRecord> findByIdentifier_UserIdAndTitleContains(String uid, String searchTerm,  Pageable pageable);
```

I'm trying to write an endpoint which will query the database and look for titles which contain certain characters. Because the titles are encrypted in the database, the query is returning no matches (it's searching the db with the encrypted "searchTerm" value.

How should I handle this? I think my options are:

1. Figure out how to not encrypt the searchTerm before searching in the database - and try to decrypt the db results before running the contains
2. Search all items in the db just by user_id, and then manually filter out the titles by the searchTerm (since the BookRecord will already have the decrypted values, this should work. Downside of this is paging becomes an issue

Any suggestions how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tough topic. Since you can't really make use of indexes due to the fact that the data is encrypted there is not much you can do, other than load the data and filter somehow. If you can implement the decryption on the database, you could at least avoid transferring unnecessary data, but the performance will still be bad if the cardinality per user_id is very high.

Comment: unfortunately, i think there is no way around it other than loading the data and then filter it on the java side. thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly it is possible to search encrypted data without decrypting it: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-releases-queryable-encryption-preview

Don't know of any relational database that does something similar and there certainly isn't any JPA integration.

Comment: Unless my understanding of how JPA works is wrong, I think it could work with JPA, as the MongoDB driver is the one doing the encryption/decryption. And as far as I know, JPA generates the query and sends it over the driver to the database. This would mean the driver should certainly be able to use the `encryption preview` (once implemented), making it work with JPA. But as you said, MongoDB seems to be the only one

Comment: I don't think there is a JPA implementation that works with MongoDB.

Comment: Seems to depend on what we define as ["works"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31941038/7109162). There seems to be some JPA support for MongoDB, but not 100% as they say that MongoDB is document based and JPA basically requires relational databases